# What are the disadvantages of running multiple test scripts with the same session ID?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, salesforce-lightning

I didn't encounter any issues, but I do require information about it.
While executing multiple test cases, it asks for an OTP. However, if I use a single session ID, it doesn't prompt for an OTP.Despite my lack of encountered issues, I find myself in need of further information on the subject. When engaged in the execution of multiple test cases, a notable phenomenon emerges: the system consistently prompts for the input of a One-Time Password (OTP), adding an additional layer of security to the process. However, intriguingly, a deviation from this pattern becomes apparent when a solitary session ID is employed. In such instances, the customary OTP prompt remarkably disappears, indicating a potential distinction in the security protocols governing these contrasting scenarios.

This disparity in OTP requirement might stem from the underlying security architecture of the system. The introduction of an OTP during multi-test case execution could be attributed to a precautionary measure, ensuring that each discrete test action is authorized and verified independently. On the contrary, the absence of OTP prompts when utilizing a single session ID could imply an established trust level associated with this specific identification method. This trust could be underpinned by prior authentication steps or the nature of the tasks executed using the session ID.

To ascertain the exact rationale behind this observed behavior and the intricacies of the security mechanisms involved, a comprehensive exploration of the system's documentation, security protocols, and session management procedures is imperative. In doing so, a holistic understanding of the interplay between OTP prompts, session IDs, and security provisions can be attained, thus facilitating informed decision-making and optimizing the testing process.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.